# Java Ant wont complete task after running a Jar

Tags: java, ant, junit4

I got some junit tests (in Tester App) that i want to run on a service (Service.jar running parallely).  As soon as ant runs Service.jar, it wouldn't return to perform the junit test as expected but just sits there running the Service app. Am i doing something wrong? My build.xml looks like this below..

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${testdir}" 
     verbose="${full-compile}">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="test" depends="compile,run">
    <junit fork="no" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <test name="xyz.Tester.Test1" outfile="result" >
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
        </test>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="run">
    <java jar="Service.jar" fork="yes">
    </java>
</target>
```

Moreover, i would like to know if there's a way i can run the Service.jar just within Ant (fork="no") if it's possible as ant wouldn't let me (Cannot execute a jar in non-forked mode. Please set fork='true'.)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As i have to launch a java job with <java>, which is to be run in parallel with ant, spawn="true" does the trick, but i dont want the job to outlive the ant process. Any suggestions yet?

Comment: Looks like <Parallel> task can take care of my problem. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ant tasks are executed in sequence. When you need to run something in parallel, you need to explicitly use task [parallel](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) - see the samples in its docs - something like:

```
...
<parallel>
  <java jar="Service.jar" fork="yes"/>
  <sequential>
    <sleep seconds="30"/>
    <junit fork="true" forkmode="once" ... >
    <java jar="ServiceStopper.jar" fork="yes"/>
  </sequential>
</parallel>
...
```

**Alternatively**, you can use the `spawn` attribute on the [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task. It causes that your service is spawned in a separate process, and processing continues with next ant command.

Concerning the non-forked jar execution - you can avoid forking if you specify `classpath` and `classname` attributes.

Comment: Thanks petr, but do i need a servicestopper for as i read, "Being daemon threads, however, they will not prevent Ant from completing, whereupon the threads are terminated."

Comment: true - but in general you may wish to run another instance with slightly different params when the first stops - of course this definitely depends on your concrete situation